# Gates of hell lock forever. What does gates of hell mean?

Tags: exegesis

Jonah 1:17 Jonah was inside the fish 3 days and nights. Jonah 2:2… Jonah went down to "the land whose gates lock forever" (Todays English Version) & Mat 16:18 (TEV) "not even death will be able to overcome it", (the church). Is the gates of hell (KJV) then death. Do we not fear being locked away, apart from God then if Jesus triumphed over the grave being 3 days and night in the belly of the earth/hell?

Answer (score 1):

The original Hebrew is only two words: "מִבֶּטֶן שְׁאֹול", one meaning "out of the belly" and the other "grave".  Some versions translate the latter word as "Hell", but most leave it alone as "Sheol".

Today's English Version isn't really a translation of the Bible though.  It is a paraphrase.  Its original purpose was to provide a Bible that is very easy for everyone to read and understand.

In many cases they had to take liberties in deciding how to express an idea without leaving it ambiguous.  In other cases, such as Jonah 2:2, they simply got carried away by poetically saying "the land whose gates lock forever" rather than "the grave".

Today's English Version (Good News Bible) is a great introduction for someone just beginning to read the Bible.  It might be compared with a grade-school history book.  For serious study, or even for trivial questions, almost any other version provides a more reliable translation.

Answer (score 1):

“And I tell you, you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of hell [or Hades] shall not prevail against it” (Matthew 16:18).  I found an article that answers this question, part of which says this:

> In ancient times, cities were surrounded by walls with gates, and in battles the gates of these cities would usually be the first place their enemies assaulted. This was because the protection of the city was determined by the strength or power of its gates.
>
> As such, the “gates of hell” or “gates of Hades” means the power of Hades. The name “Hades” was originally the name of the god who presided over the realm of the dead and was often referred to as the “house of Hades.” It designated the place to which everyone who departs this life descends, regardless of their moral character. In the New Testament, Hades is the realm of the dead, and in this verse Hades or hell is represented as a mighty city with its gates representing its power.
>
> Jesus refers here to His impending death. Though He would be crucified and buried, He would rise from the dead and build His church. Jesus is emphasizing the fact that the powers of death could not hold Him in. Not only would the church be established in spite of the powers of Hades or hell, but the church would thrive in spite of these powers. The church will never fail, though generation after generation succumbs to the power of physical death, yet other generations will arise to perpetuate the church.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/gates-of-hell.html

Because “death no longer is master over Him” (Romans 6:9), it is no longer master over those who belong to Christ Jesus.